# How can I specify an E-Mail address when signing a binary file?

Tags: windows, email, digital-signature, signtool

I'm using [signtool](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/8s9b9yaz%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to apply a digital signature to various `.exe`/`.dll` files. However, viewing the signed files in Windows Explorer shows that no E-Mail address is set, much like in this screenshot (I'm by no means affiliated with "Paramount Software UK Ltd." -- this screenshots is just the first result I found via Google):

[image: Screenshot of Windows explorer showing signature details without e-mail address]

However, I also saw other screenshots showing that it's somehow possible to define an E-Mail address (even if it's a bogus one, like in this case):

[image: Screenshot of Windows explorer showing signature details including e-mail address]

Is it possible to set this E-mail address via `signtool`, or is it actually a property of the certificate itself (i.e. it needs to be specified when purchasing a certificate)?

Comment: I expect it's a property of the certificate that you're signing with, and you'll need to get a new certificate that includes your email. I've definitely seen a field for in when generating CSRs with OpenSSL.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The email property it's extracted from `emailAddress` in a `subject distinguished name` field of your certificate.

You can make a test using openssl to generate a selfsigned certificate (then you can generate a `CSR` with an `emailAddress` and send to the certificate authority to generate a valid end-entity certificate). To test it you can do the follow steps:

Generate self-signed certificate using the follow `openssl` command

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
```

Then you will be asked to enter the follow parameters (all for a subject of the certificate):

[image]

To avoid this prompt you can directly specify the `subject` in the previous command using `-subj` as follow:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -subj "/C=ES/ST=58/L=Barcelona/O=yourOrgName/OU=yourDept/CN=yourAppName/emailAddress=myEmail@test.com"
```

Now you can generate a `p12` (or `pfx`) from the generated key and cert using the follow command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out myTestWithMail.pfx -inkey key.pem -in cert.pem
```

Now you have a `p12` (myTestWithMail.pfx), that you can use to sign an `exe` or `dll` using the follow `signtool` command. For example I sign `notepad++.exe` (as in the examples you link in your question):

```
signtool.exe sign /f C:\Users\Albert\myTestWithMail.pfx /p 1234 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe"
```

Note that `/f` is for the path of your signing key, and `/p` is the password for your key.

Now you can see the email in the file you sign:

[image]

So finally if you need a certificate from a certificate authority you have to generate the `CSR` specifying `emailAddress` for example using `openssl` command:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -out yourAppName.csr -keyout yourAppName.key -subj "/C=ES/ST=58/L=Barcelona/O=yourOrgName/OU=yourDept/CN=yourAppName/emailAddress=myEmail@test.com"
```

Or alternatively without specifying `-subj` parameter and enter the correct values for subject distinguished name when are prompted:

```
openssl req -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -out yourAppName.csr -keyout yourAppName.key
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 5):

Short answer: *Yes*, the e-mail address is part of the certificate and *no*, you cannot specify it when signing a binary file.

Long answer: @albciff pointed out how to generate a certificate which has an email address associated with it but it seems you're out of luck in case you bought the certificate from [Thawte](https://www.thawte.com/); my colleague asked this exact question to the technical support of our certificate provider (Thawte) which replied:

> When enrolling for a Code Signing certificate the email address used is not part of the validation process. Unfortunately, because the email is not part of the validation process it will not be included in the properties of the signed code.

Furthermore, tech support referred us to
[this article](https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=SO3877&actp=search&viewlocale=en_US&searchid=1424200577342) in the 'Thawte Knowledge Center' which explains:

> The e-mail address always appears as "not available" when viewing the properties of signed code. This is because the certificate validates the organization but requires no information about the e-mail address of the organization. Thus, we have validated the organization, but have not validated the e-mail. This in no way lessens the value or usefulness of your ID.

So not only is the email address part of the certificate, whether you can associate an email address with the certificate also depends on who issued the certificate.

Comment: @FrerichRabbe so as I said technically it's possible but for some certificate authorities you can't use `emailAddress` because they can't validate it... at least with `Thawte`...  `Thawte` behavior for this case sounds ridiculous to me since they're validating all other data (enterprise etc) an issuing finally a certificate ... why they cannot validate the `email`?. Anyway as you said you can try with other certificate authority.